# web2py transparent label

Tags: javascript, python, web2py

now in web2py every field in the db look like this in the form

```
Label : [            ]
```

i'm using the custom form so i removed all labels and i want to show them as transparent bacground in the `input` and `textarea` and set the first option to the label in `select`

here is the customization

```
<div>{{=form.custom.widget.field}}</div>
```

i want it to look like this

```
inputs/textareas:
[ label ]
selects:
[ -- label -- [v]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{label = form.custom.label.field}}
```

For input fields you can use the `placeholder` attribute:

```
{{form.element(_name='fieldname')['_placeholder'] = label}}
<div>{{=form.custom.widget.field}}</div>
```

For your select fields:

```
{{form.custom.widget.field.element('option').append(label)}}
<div>{{=form.custom.widget.field}}</div>
```

Comment: thanks, i tried your solution but i dont get anything it stills empty!
im using chrome btw

Comment: but it works with jquery
`$('#table_field').attr('placeholder','test');`